.htaccess trying to create Clean URLs mod_rewrite
I have read prior SO questions and read tutorials and I do not understand mod_rewrite fully so I am posting here
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/index\.php\?var=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/featured/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/featured/(.*?)/?$ $1/index.php?var=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/ /profile.php?userid=$3 [NC, L] 

I would like to take www. domain.com / profile.php?userid=2343 and rewrite the URL to a clean URL which is www.domain . com/profile/2343/
I have tried a number of variations.. the .htaccess code described above does not work.
Help please?

With your shown attempts, samples. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#### 1st set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/index\.php\?var=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/featured/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/featured/(.*?)/?$ $1/index.php?var=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


#### 2nd set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(profile)\.php\?userid=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(profile)/(.*?)/?$ $1.php?userid=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


I have about 30 different virtual folders I want to create though.. (users/ groups/ profile/preferences/ groups/groupname/ submit/  etc... so for each virtual dir I have to add a new set of rules?   my htaccess file will become very long

@bobafart, we need to find out Pattern comman between them else if there is no patten then there will be no option.

thanks @ravindersingh13    what if I have this URL:  https://www.
domain .com/content/cat/build  and it points to www. domain .com/content/catcontent.php?catvar=build     ??   what htaccess mod_rewrite rule would it follow?

@bobafart, sure it's little different. You could open a new question and let me know we can discuss it there, cheers.

ok done thanks for the help.  I have posted a fresh question with your help

@bobafart, sorry I can't see it. Please post link here.

Thanks for responding and for your help.. here it is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79173435/how-to-write-a-clean-url-with-mod-rewrite-using-virtual-dirs-actual-dirs-and-va
