How to write a clean URL with mod_rewrite using virtual dirs, actual dirs and variables as a combination
I have read prior questions and read tutorials and I do not understand mod_rewrite fully so I am posting here.  My current .htaccess is:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#### 1st set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/index\.php\?var=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/featured/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/featured/(.*?)/?$ $1/index.php?var=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


#### 2nd set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(profile)\.php\?userid=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(profile)/(.*?)/?$ $1.php?userid=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

I have this URL: www. domain .com/content/cat/build and it points to www. domain .com/content/catcontent.php?catvar=build ?? what htaccess mod_rewrite rule would it follow?
I have added this but it breaks the site...
   #### 3rd set of rules.... ####
    #Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/(cat)/\catview\.php\?cattype=(.*?)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(content)/(cat)/catview.php/?$ $1.php?cattype=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

Thanks
I have googled and read old posts.  I have read tutorials.  I do not understand mod_rewrite that well since it seems like an alphanumeric word salad and am asking for assistance

With your shown samples, please try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#### 1st set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(content)/index\.php\?var=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/featured/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/featured/(.*?)/?$ $1/index.php?var=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
##############################

#### 2nd set of rules.... ####
#Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(profile)\.php\?userid=(.*?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(profile)/(.*?)/?$ $1.php?userid=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
##############################

#### 3rd set of rules from here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(content)/(cat)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/$2$1.php?catvar=$3 [QSA,NC,L]


Thanks Ravinder... doesnt seem to work. I did clear the cache before testing...... URL is domain . com /content/catcontent.php?catvar=Grow but doesnt redirect to load the document at domain . com /content/cat/build

@bobafart, what url you are hitting?

I am accessing the approrpriate URL but I cannot post the actual domain on stack overflow because it wont let me.        If catvar=Build it works fine.... but if any other category is included (like "market", "grow", "wiki" - I have a number of categories) then it doesnt redirect... the mod_rewrite doesnt work.   the URL is domain/content/catcontent.php?catvar=$var   where $var is a string of one of many categories

@bobafart, I edited the answer please do check and let me know then.

Yes sir.  Sorry for not replying sooner.  I was testing it out all last night!  Seems to work with different variations and your solution has deepened my understanding about confusing mod_rewrites.. I never understood them but I think I am one step closer now.  thanks.. best answer provided by you as always!

@bobafart, your welcome, happy to help. keep learning and keep sharing cheers,

...make sure to clear your browser cache - An important point.
